# "I kept sleeping" or "I kept asleep"

Tags: sentence-construction

> I kept sleeping.

or

> I kept asleep.

Which is correct? I have gotten different opinions.

Comment: *Kept asleep* is causative...you helped something else stay asleep: "I kept the kittie asleep by covering it with a blanket."

Comment: Exactly what do you mean? Do you mean that you continued to sleep, possibly in spite of the events that might, or should have woken you up or do you have some other context in mind?

Comment: Thank you yosef. Can i say 'I keep alive" (in a sense of myself).

Comment: Yes Boldben i mean i continued to sleep.

Comment: How about "I keep awake" and "I keep waking up" what is the difference.

Comment: @BilalZafar "I keep awake" - awake here is likely an adjective, so you want "stayed".  "I keep waking up" - "waking-up" is a verb so "keep" is correct.
For "I keep alive", I'd suggest consulting the Bee Gees https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I_izvAbhExY

Answer (score 5):

"Keep" in this sense, when used without an object, is usually followed by a verb. ("Sleeping" is the present participle, not the gerund, here.) So

> I kept sleeping"

is preferred.

The exception is adjectives of position, so "I kept away" "I kept close" is fine too.

With other adjectives "stayed" is preferred over "kept".

> I stayed asleep

is also good.

When used with an object "kept" is good.

> I kept him asleep.

Comment: Thank you DJCLayworth. Can i say "I keep alive"(in a sense of myself)

Comment: What about "I keep awake" and "I keep waking up" is it the same rule as you mentioned earlier for asleep or different?

Comment: "I keep alive" is wrong as per this rule, so you would say "I stay alive" or "I keep living". As for your second example, "I keep awake" is also wrong per this rule. "I stay awake" means you don't fall asleep, but "I keep waking up" would mean that you sleep but wake up multiple times during your sleep.

Comment: The rule is what I said. "I kept <adjective>" is wrong except for adjectives of position.

Comment: But "keep awake" is fine because it involves effort. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

As you have confirmed that you mean "I continued to sleep" what you should say is "I kept *on* sleeping" or "I *stayed* asleep". Neither of the options you suggested is normal English.

Comment: Thank you BoldBen. May i know the difference between "I keep awake" and "I keep on waking up"

Comment: @BilalZafar Please ask another question.

Comment: Thank you DJClayworth for replying. Infact i just got it clear.

Comment: I don't know if it's strictly grammatical to say "kept sleeping", but I sure do hear a lot of native speakers say things like that (which is probably sufficient to call it "normal English").

Comment: @NotThatGuy You do, quite correctly, hear "kept sleeping" but I contend that it is in the context of habitual sleep patterns, not of a particular episode of sleep. For example: "I kept sleeping badly because my twisted shoulder would wake me up", "I kept sleeping on the sofa when I came home drunk. Eventually my wife divorced me"

Comment: @BilalZafar "I keep awake" refers to the habitual, deliberate practice of not sleeping but "I keep on waking up" refers to the habitual tendency to wake from sleep. For instance "I keep awake when I work night shifts by drinking lots of coffee", (if you are working night shifts you can lose your job if you fall asleep) as opposed to "I keep waking up in the night if I drink coffee before I go to bed" (if the speaker drinks coffee before going to bed it stops them sleeping properly.

Comment: @BoldBen I've specifically heard it to express continuity, not (just) habit, e.g. "My injury started acting up during the race, but I kept running". Although one might contest that "kept" to express continuity would be more of an active choice, which isn't actually possible for "kept sleeping" (if you're asleep, you can't make an active choice, and if you're awake, you can only fall back asleep, not "keep" being asleep).

Comment: @NotThatGuy I tbink that you have a good point there, although "I kept _on_ running" is also possible, in fact I as an Ancient Briton would be more likely to use it and I feel that "kept running" in this case is an elided form of "kept on running" which has become more common over fairly recent time. I also think that it is more acceptable for something which involves conciousness, if not concious effort. Keeping (on) running with an injury will certainly require concious effort, staying asleep, by definition, does not.

Answer (score 1):

`kept sleeping` is the proper way here.

Saying `asleep` is mentioning that you are currently sleeping. Doesn't match with proper english grammar.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. When describing an activity or state, I think it matters whether "keep" implies maintaining the activity/state on purpose, or merely means the activity/state is continuing on its own.

If there is a conscious decision or exertion of effort, an adjective is OK: *I barely managed to keep **awake** through the boring presentation*; *I kept **quiet***. But **keep asleep* is weird because you are not purposefully staying asleep.

As others have noted, with an object there is causation, and an adjective is OK because the subject is making an effort: *I kept him asleep*.

If the subject of the sentence is inanimate and thus unable to act, an adjective does not work: **the prices kept high*.

The present participle is always OK: *I kept sleeping*; *The prices kept rising*.

Note that there are [many senses of "keep"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/keep) and they may have different grammatical constraints.

Answer (score 1):

[TL;DR](https://www.businessinsider.com/tldr-meaning): "I kept asleep" is not grammatical or idiomatic English.  "I kept sleeping" is correct.

---

The verb ["keep"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/keep#Verb) has many different uses that require different kinds of grammar (and, in fact, often the grammatical context is what allows you to tell which sense of "keep" is intended).

The sense relevant to your question, meaning "to continue or repeat an action", always takes a verb in [the *-ing* form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/-ing) (i.e. a present participle) as a complement:

> "I kept walking." (= "I continued to walk.")
> "He keeps coming back." (= "He has come back several times, and will likely come back again.")
> "I kept waking up." (= "I woke up several times.")
> "We will keep trying." (= "We have tried before, and we will try again.")

There *is* a related sense, meaning "to remain in a state", that takes an adjective instead, as in:

> "I kept quiet." (= "I stayed quiet." / "I did not say anything.")
> "We kept away from them." (= "We avoided them." / "We did not go near them.")
> "Keep strong!" (= "Remain strong!" / "Do not give up!")

However, that particular sense of "keep" is normally used only in with a limited number of adjectives that typically relate to to *active avoidance of something*.  When you're asleep, you don't normally do *anything* actively, so it does not make sense to say that you "kept asleep" — that would imply that you 1) knew you were asleep, 2) did not want to wake up, and 3) expended some mental effort to avoid waking up.  This is usually not the case, so saying that you "kept asleep" is not only weird and unidiomatic — it is also arguably at least borderline ungrammatical, as "asleep" is not one of the few adjectives that can be used with "keep" in this sense.

However, you *can* idiomatically say:

> "I kept awake."

implying that you stayed awake and actively avoided falling asleep, even though you were tired and might've fallen asleep if you didn't resist it.  (On the other hand, if you had insomnia and stayed awake even though you *wanted* to fall asleep, then you would *not* usually say that you "kept awake", but merely that you "stayed" or "was" awake.)

Admittedly it's not one of the most common usages of "keep" + *adjective*, but it's fairly easy to find examples of it* and fluent speakers would normally recognize the usage in context without finding it in any way unusual.

---

*) Well, at least it's easy if you choose your search terms carefully to avoid instances of the much more common *transitive* usage of "keep awake", meaning "to prevent someone from sleeping" (as in "The noise kept me awake").  Just searching for [the phrase "I kept awake"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I+kept+awake%22&tbm=bks) works fairly well.